Simulating a Random Shapefile
I have this code in R for simulating a country with different neighborhoods:
library(igraph)

width <- 30
height <- 20
num_nodes <- width * height

x <- rep(1:width, each = height)
y <- rep(1:height, times = width)

g <- make_empty_graph(n = num_nodes, directed = FALSE)

get_node_index <- function(i, j) (i - 1) * height + j

# Add edges
edges <- c()
for(i in 1:width) {
  for(j in 1:height) {
    current_node <- get_node_index(i, j)
    if(i < width) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i + 1, j))
    if(j < height) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i, j + 1))
  }
}
g <- add_edges(g, edges)

V(g)$x <- x
V(g)$y <- y

V(g)$color <- sample(c("red", "blue"), num_nodes, replace = TRUE)

count_patches <- function(color) {
  subgraph <- induced_subgraph(g, V(g)[V(g)$color == color])
  components <- components(subgraph)
  return(components$no)
}

plot(g, layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y), 
     vertex.size = 7,  
     vertex.label = NA,
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
     edge.color = "lightgray"
     )


However, this is just assigning random colors to each node.
I am trying to make the colors more in "clusters" to resemble a more natural pattern like  this:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Texas_gubernatorial_election_maps#/media/File:TXGov1990Map.png
Can this be done in R using the spatstat package?
Random fields idea:
library(igraph)
library(fields)  

width <- 30
height <- 20
num_nodes <- width * height
x <- rep(1:width, each = height)
y <- rep(1:height, times = width)
g <- make_empty_graph(n = num_nodes, directed = FALSE)

get_node_index <- function(i, j) (i - 1) * height + j

edges <- c()
for(i in 1:width) {
  for(j in 1:height) {
    current_node <- get_node_index(i, j)
    if(i < width) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i + 1, j))
    if(j < height) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i, j + 1))
  }
}
g <- add_edges(g, edges)

V(g)$x <- x
V(g)$y <- y

# Gaussian Random Field simulation
set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
spatial_correlation <- 5  # Adjust this to control the size of clusters

# Create  grid
grf <- fields::Exp.image.cov(grid = list(x = 1:width, y = 1:height), 
                             theta = spatial_correlation, setup = TRUE)

# simulate the Gaussian random field
sim <- fields::sim.rf(grf)

# Assign colors based on the Gaussian random field
threshold <- 0  # Adjust this to control the balance between colors
V(g)$color <- ifelse(sim > threshold, "red", "blue")

=plot(g, layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y),
     vertex.size = 7, vertex.label = NA,
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5, edge.color = "lightgray")



EDIT: Using the answer below, I adapted the code to make a random network with this same clustering effect:
library(igraph)
library(fields)

n_points <- 600
space_size <- 30
connection_radius <- 2.5

set.seed(123)
x <- runif(n_points, 0, space_size)
y <- runif(n_points, 0, space_size)

positions <- cbind(x, y)
g <- graph.empty(n = n_points, directed = FALSE)
for(i in 1:(n_points-1)) {
    for(j in (i+1):n_points) {
        dist <- sqrt((x[i] - x[j])^2 + (y[i] - y[j])^2)
        if(dist < connection_radius) {
            g <- add_edges(g, c(i,j))
        }
    }
}

V(g)$x <- x
V(g)$y <- y

spatial_correlation <- 5
n_grid <- 50
grid_x <- seq(0, space_size, length.out = n_grid)
grid_y <- seq(0, space_size, length.out = n_grid)

grf <- fields::Exp.image.cov(grid = list(x = grid_x, y = grid_y), 
                             theta = spatial_correlation, setup = TRUE)

sim <- fields::sim.rf(grf)

get_grid_value <- function(x, y, sim, grid_x, grid_y) {
    ix <- which.min(abs(grid_x - x))
    iy <- which.min(abs(grid_y - y))
    return(sim[ix, iy])
}

node_values <- sapply(1:n_points, function(i) {
    get_grid_value(x[i], y[i], sim, grid_x, grid_y)
})
threshold <- 0
V(g)$color <- ifelse(node_values > threshold, "red", "blue")

count_patches <- function(color) {
    subgraph <- induced_subgraph(g, V(g)[V(g)$color == color])
    components <- components(subgraph)
    return(components$no)
}

plot(g, layout = positions,
     vertex.size = 3,
     vertex.label = NA,
     edge.arrow.size = 0,
     edge.color = "lightgray",
     edge.width = 0.5)



Hard to help unless you can be a bit more precise. Are you only interested in an NxM grid of cells? How much control do you want over the spatial correlation? Is it only two categories? As a quick approximation, generate a gaussian random field over the grid with a given spatial correlation parameter and threshold at some value should get you clusters. The RandomFields package maybe... Will play if I get a chance later.

I tried somethings like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78949381/how-to-tell-if-a-point-has-been-colored-twice-in-r ... thank you for the guassian random field idea ... suppose i want "n" categories , spatial correlation can be set to some constant ... I am interested in any network, i just thought an nxm is easy to visualize for people on the internet ...

looking forward to hearing your answer...

I have no idea about random fields.. I tried to read online and piece something together (see update)

One slight problem in your code fixed, I still don't know why you are using igraph to do this on a network though, rather than either a set of X-Y spatial points on a grid, or not on a grid, or a set of polygons.

Your code is filling the grid in the wrong direction. Transpose the simulated matrix:
# simulate the Gaussian random field
sim <- t(fields::sim.rf(grf))

and then you'll get the clustering effect I was expecting:


thank you! In this approach, it is impossible to say how many clusters we want - correct?

Yes. That's a whole 'nother problem. Tweaking the threshold might get you there, but there's no guarantee even that will give you a desired number.

thanks for the feedback ... btw here are some approaches I had tried in the past https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78949381/how-to-tell-if-a-point-has-been-colored-twice-in-r
